# Substr certain parts from a column in Pandas DataFrame based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like below:

```
 id         Name              New_Name
100263   Test Index (UHD)    Test Index
100264   Test Num             Test Num
```

As you can see when the value in my `Name` column contains `(`, I only want to the left part of this string, for example: `Test Index (UHD)`-> `Test Index`; however, if the string doesn’t include `(`, I want the whole string, for example: `Test Num`-> `Test Num`

I have an idea that I can loops through all the values in this column in order to make the change,for example for the first value, my thought is

```
try:
    pos=data.iloc[0,1].index('(')
except:
    pos=len(data.iloc[0,1])

New_Name =data.iloc[0,2][:pos]
```

I don't think it should be that complex, so there is any easy way to do this?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you only have one parenthesis component you can simplify the invocation like this

```
data[ 'New_Name' ] = data.Name.apply( lambda s: s.split( '(', 1 )[ 0 ].strip() )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with a simple `regex`

```
regex = re.compile(r'.*?(\(.*?\))')
def strip_brackets(x):    
    result = re.findall(regex, x)
    for r in result:
        x = x.replace(r, '')
    return ' '.join(x.split())

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Test Index (UHD)', 'Test Num', 'More (foo) complicated (bar) case']})
df['NewName'] = df['Name'].apply(strip_brackets)
print(df)


                                Name                NewName
0                   Test Index (UHD)             Test Index
1                           Test Num               Test Num
2  More (foo) complicated (bar) case  More complicated case
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner to remove anything under parenthesis:

```
df['New_Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

Output:

```
>>df

 id         Name              New_Name
100263   Test Index (UHD)    Test Index
100264   Test Num             Test Num
```